# ExtJs Grid state not save when more than one instance used

Tags: extjs, grid, stateful

According to the document , I have setted the property："stateful" , "stateId" and added the code below when ExtJs loaded:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*7)), //7 days from now
}));
```

The state of grid saved successfully when the whole page reload, but when I instance a new Grid at the same page, the state not save, how to fix it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The stateId property for each Grid or any other component in your app should be different.

Are you following that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this `stateId: string` , `stateful: true,` and `stateEvents: ['columnresize', 'columnmove', 'show', 'hide'],` in your gridpanel.

Hope, It might be work. :)